# Ubuntu 18.04 video issues in all browsers

Tags: gnome, 18.04, video, browser

An odd issue since clean install of 18.04 (using standard Ubuntu Gnome 3 or straight up Gnome 3) - video stutters only in browsers, absolutely fine otherwise. This effects all browsers and all types of video.

I have found that if I change to Gnome Flashback, the issue disappears, same with Xfce and Plasma (haven't gone through all the DE's yet).

Why is this an issue with Gnome 3 specifically? Yes, I want to keep using Gnome 3 because I like it.

AMD-FX 6300 6 core cpu
16 GB ddr3 ram
Nvidia 1050 ti 4 GB <-- Definitely NOT the problem, as other DE's are fine

EDIT - Because Nvidia and Wayland do not get along, my default sessions are xorg. And I have tried using the Nouveau drivers with the same exact results as mentioned above.

Comment: Not Wayland, as it doesn't support Nvidia (or the other way round). I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: I think nouveau supports Wayland.

Comment: Have you tried to alter the video playback rate? See also [Youtube micro-stutter after 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029485/youtube-micro-stutter-after-18-04). There is also the possibility of changing Ubuntu flavour... See [Ubuntu 16.04 / 18.04 video playback lags / stutters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/447696/ubuntu-16-04-18-04-video-playback-lags-stutters).

Comment: @ElToro1966 - The first link seems to have a possible answer. I am testing out the change in refresh rate, and it is making the video appear smoother. I will test further, and if it continues to work, I will make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @ElToro1966 - After some testing I have found that, while this improves video playback, there is still some stuttering. Better, but not quite. Definitely an issue with Gnome 3 alone.

Comment: If Gnome 3 (my DE) is the issue, then why am I and most other users, not affected by this video stutter?

Comment: @PaulBenson - I couldn't tell you. I just know it stutters only on Gnome 3. I have 2 boxes, and both have this issue.